# How to lower app notification volume

Tags: macbook-pro, notifications, system-settings, big-sur, sound-volume

I have a new MacBook Pro running Big Sur. The sound effect for individual app notifications, such as Chrome or Slack, is much louder than other sounds on my machine and I would like a way to lower their volume without changing the system volume.

I have gone to System Preferences > Sound > Sound Effects and lowered Alert volume but it has no effect on these sounds. For example, if I move the 'Alert volume' slider all the way to the left to where I hear no sound at all from that panel, but leave the system volume around the middle, the notification sounds I get from, apps like Slack are still extremely loud. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Alert Volume seems to work just fine for me, is your mac up-to-date?

Comment: Yep, I'm on the latest version of Big Sur. It is a managed work computer. Is there any chance that something with that is causing issues?

Comment: Don't know,

I presume you have tried restarting?

Comment: I noticed the same issue.   When I close System Preferences and reopen the "Alert volume" slider is all the way back to the loudest setting.  Did you manage to figure out what's causing this?

Comment: @jan, nope I never figured out a solution and ended up silencing notification sounds from individual apps like Slack. The missed notifications are less of a problem than blowing out my eardrums. I would love to know if anyone ever finds a solution for this.